# How much business has Bitcoin brought Meze Grill up to now?

Tags: business

(Up and including August 2011)

[Meze Grill](http://mezegrill.com/) was the first restaurant to accept Bitcoin. Has this option generated revenue for them?

Comment: See on Meta: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-questions-on-how-much-bitcoin-does-a-person-business-have-fair-game/6#6